# Как изменить стили select в materialize

Tags: css, css3, materialize-css

Нужно изменить стили select, но он не реагирует. Materialize подключал через cdn.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select').formSelect();
});
```

```css
option {
   color: red;
   background: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
 
 <div class="input-field">
     <select class="">
       <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
       <option value="1">Option 1</option>
       <option value="2">Option 2</option>
       <option value="3">Option 3</option>
     </select>
 </div>
 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S.: Пользуйтесь браузерным инспектором

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').formSelect();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<style>
  .dropdown-content li>span {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div class="input-field">
  <select class="">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```